# Convert Photoshop Shape into Path, so I can delete certain points of the shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I made a custom shape using the 'custom shape' tool in photoshop. I want to convert this to a path so that I can delete certain points from the shape and make a new shape.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Direct Selection Tool (or press <kbd>A</kbd>), then <kbd>Double Click</kbd> on the path. You will then see the anchors, which you can delete/move or add more

[image]

Comment: Thank you! how do I move a path? The only way I've found is to use the direct selection tool, select all the anchors, and nudge them around with the arrow keys... I figured there was a simpler way using the move tool, but using it and just clicking and dragging on the path doesn't seem to do anything.